# Is there any other way to pause current running process and run it in background other than Ctrl+Z followed by bg?

Tags: linux, terminal, java, mongodb

I'm trying to run several mongod processes through a Java Application using ProcessBuilder, is there a way to simulate Ctrl+Z keypress to pause the current mongod process ?

Comment: What is the problem with CTRL+Z? Why do you need to simulate it?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with kill. To pause a process do
`kill -STOP <pid>` and to continue it `kill -CONT <pid>`.

Comment: This will work at the condition the process killed handles SIGSTOP/SIGCONT in some other way than SIG_IGN. Applied to mongodb processes, OP should check, I remember that (long time ago) mongodb had no proper support for these signals. Sure things might have changed so check first. Anyhow whenever killing whatever, always first check that the signal is handled according to what you expect.

Comment: @MC68020, `SIGSTOP` (as opposed to `SIGTSTP`) **cannot** be blocked, ignored or handled. When running CTRL+Z, it actually sends `SIGSTP` to the process. So if you **really** want to simulate CTRL+Z, you should use `kill -TSTP`. It should also be added to the answer, since usually it is better to use `SIGTSTP` to allow the application to handle it gracefully using a signal handler. `SIGSTOP` should be use If `SIGTSTP` fails (due to the signal being blocked/ignored).